# How to run an external javascript file in powershell while sending mail through powershell to outlook

Tags: javascript, email, powershell, outlook

```
$file1='http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRdbaQlyhJe1PWm88LDsa9DEz-nqK0BR0dkPGL1GYdpVOnmdvpcQ'
$file2='http://images.clipartlogo.com/files/ss/thumb/709/70951033/illustration-of-red-cross-mark_small.jpg'

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$Mail.To = "email1"
$Mail.Recipients.Add("email2")
$Mail.Subject = "New Request"
$Mail.HTMLBody = " <a href='http://www.w3schools.com'><input type='image' src='$file1' name='approve' value='Submit'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='https://www.google.co.in/'><input type='image' src='$file2' name='reject' value='Submit'/></a> <br/>"
$Mail.HTMLBody += "Kindly approve/reject the request"

$Mail.Send()
```

I am using above powershell script to send email to an outlook email address. Now i want to include an external javascript file that is located on my laptop and want to use this script in above code for doing some work with the images.

Comment: What does the javascript do? I would expect that to be run in a browser. Others have explored that https://gist.github.com/omidkrad/fbb4bfb3b1f5b83c9898

Comment: @Matt I would like to know that how can i have a javascript file included in the powershell script.